# how can I access to a hashed key stored by spring redis session using RedisTemplate?

Tags: java, spring, session, redis

I have this problem.

There is a spring session stored in redis,saved [this way](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H2OPk.png)

```
HMSET spring:session:sessions:33fdd1b6-b496-4b33-9f7d-df96679d32fe creationTime 1404360000000 \
    maxInactiveInterval 1800 \
    lastAccessedTime 1404360000000 \
    sessionAttr:attrName someAttrValue \
    sessionAttr2:attrName someAttrValue2
```

As far as I understand is a hashed set.

I can access it via redis-cli with [HMGET](https://redis.io/commands/hmget)  that as far as I understand is to get values of hashed keys.

Works great.

Now on spring, I want to access it via Redis Template (org.springframework.data.redis.core).

So, I did this

@Autowired
RedisOperationsSessionRepository redisOperationsSessionRepository;

@Autowired
RedisTemplate redisTemplate;

and tried...

stringRedisTemplate.opsForValue().get(loggedSessionId);

```
redisTemplate.opsForHash().get("mykey", WHAT GOES HERE?)
redisOperationsSessionRepository.sessionRedisOperations.opsForHash().get(mykey", OR HERE?)
```

so far I cannot access it to the information, any idea what hash I have to define? there is no info how spring gets it ...

Thanks.

EDIT:

What I basically want to do is

COPY this

[image]

and save it in other redis using another template...

as you can see, it has not the value serialized in right way, could be a problem if I just copy and "paste" the objects using opsForHash or will I save corrupted data?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quote from https://redis.io/topics/data-types

> Redis Hashes are maps between string fields and string values ...

So

```
redisTemplate.opsForHash().get("mykey", "myKeyHash")
```

Will return value of the field *myKeyHash* stored in key *mykey*.

For your examle your fileds would be *creationTime*, *maxInactiveInterval*, *lastAccessedTime* and attributes.

By the way there is a more convinient method:

```
redisTemplate.opsForHash().entries("mykey")
```

that returns map of all fileds contained in that hash with their values.

**EDIT**

Since Spring uses *JdkSerializationRedisSerializer* for valules and *StringRedisSerializer* for keys/hash keys, you must configure your RedistTemplate as follows to be able to read data correctly:

```
RedisTemplate<String, Object> template = new RedisTemplate<>(); 
RedisSerializer stringSerializer = new StringRedisSerializer();
template.setConnectionFactory(...); 
template.setKeySerializer(stringSerializer); 
template.setHashKeySerializer(stringSerializer);
```

Comment: is there any converter i must specify when creating my redis template??

Comment: and... what kind of object is the value from "sessionAttr:SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT" ?

Comment: Thanks @chimmi, do you know if there is any easier way to get the user principal currently logged with data saved in redis?

Comment: @jpganz18 If you want current user, why do you Redis? Why can`t you just pull it from SecurityContextHolder or http session?

Comment: because I am running it by a filter before the session filter runs, when I run my filter there is no info of the user principal in the request information

Comment: I think you are missing something because session must be present when your filter runs. Spring security context may not yet be populated but session must present and it should contain principal attribute. Anyway, the bottom line is this: either you pulling principal from session attribute or you load it from Redis you still need http session. Because in later case you need session id which is part of the Redis key.

Comment: yes, but I need to pass this filter before the sessions and for that I need to parse it from the redis key, any idea how?

Comment: Again, if you somehow managed to run your filter before http session is properly instantiated, you won't be able to get id of said session, which you need to figure out Redis key.

Comment: I do since I can read the cookie to get the session id, inside spring:session:sessions:123456 all the information comes up and the user details inside the security context key "sessionAttr:SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT"

Comment: You can do that, if it works for you. Although I just checked, and session id does not always exactly equals cookie value.

Comment: I have that done but the serializer keeps doing wrong stuff, any idea how can I know the serializer I should use?

Comment: What I basically want to do is when using redis to save spring sessions, before go to "read" it from redis, perform other actions in other redis...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150144/discussion-between-chimmi-and-jpganz18).